# socket.on doesn't work outside io.sockets.on('connection,..)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have tried to catch a message from a routing page in this way:

**ROUTING PAGE**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
        var socket= req.app.get('socketio');
        socket.on('Ok', () => console.log("OK"));
        res.render('exercises', {title: 'Exercises', ex: values[0]});
    })
```

**APP.JS**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connesso');
    app.set('socketio', socket);
})
```

In order to catch an 'Ok' event from the client in the routing page, but it's doesn't work and I don't figure out why because I've passed socket with app.set

**EDIT**
I emit the event here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');
    </script>
    <div id="addex" hidden>
        <form name="newex" method="get">
            <h1>Inserisci esercizio</h1>
            <p>Nome</p>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text"></input>
            <p>Descrizione</p>
            <input id="description" name="description" type="text"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button id="add" type="button" onclick=""> Add </button>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <ul>
    <p>Excercises:</p>
     <% ex.forEach(value => { %>
     <li><%= value.name %></li>
    <% }); %>

    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        add.onclick = function(event){
            addex.hidden = false;
        }
        newex.onsubmit = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('message', {name: document.getElementById('name').value, desc: document.getElementById('description').value});

        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can see from edit now, sorry I forgot that.

Comment: Yes but if I catch the event inside console.log('Connesso') then I need to import database files into app.js in order to responde to event, and if I do it for every request, app.js will be a mess. I'm trying to keep app.js clean. I don't know if I've been clear in the explanation

Comment: It doesn't work with 'message' too. I'm wrong to copy script inside stackoverflow

Comment: If I understand correctly, You want to fire an even from the web page and listen to the even on the routing code?

Comment: Yeah, I want to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this example:

```
const socketServer = SocketService.io = socketIo(server, {
    path: process.env.WEBSOCKETS_PATH || "/socket.io",
    handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
        const headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin ? req.headers.origin : "*", // or the specific origin you want to give access to,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        };
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        res.end();
    },
});

export let socketConnection;

socketServer.on("connect", async (connection) => {
    logger.log("Successfully established socket connection.");
    connection.emit("connection", { code: 200, message: "Socket connection established." });
    socketConnection = connection;
    connection.on("my event", async (streamConnection) => {
        logger.log("Successfully established socket my event.");
        connection.emit("connection", { code: 200, message: "My event established, listening on 'my event' event." });
    });
});
```

Now in some other part of code you can import 'socketConnection', and use it.

Answer (score 0):

`.emit` is to fire an event and `.on` listens for event.

With that being so, In your router code by doing `socket.on('Ok', () => console.log("OK"));` you are trying to listen to an event named `Ok`.

Now to listen to that event, there has to be an event fired named `Ok`. In your client by doing this `socket.emit('message', ...)` you are firing an event named `message`.

In your given code I don't see if you need this message or not but summary is to listen to and event named `Ok` you have to `socket.emit('Ok', ...)` somewhere else; your client in this case.

This is the bare basic of `socket.io`. I suggest you check the documentations and some tutorials because it was confusing for me in the beginning as well :)

Hope that helps you!

Cheers!

Comment: I changed the line socket.on('Ok', () => console.log("OK")); with socket.on('message', () => console.log("OK")); but it's still not working

Comment: Well without seeing how your application flow is, I can not answer that question but the function on the route I don't think it is valid to listen there like this since after the last line it's execution should come to an end. Maybe you need to do something asynchronous. What is your goal here?